# Reduce objects to objects and arrays when Express query returns multiple objects on a many to many query

Tags: javascript, express

I have some SQL queries that I'm running return multiple objects when we have a many to many mapping in express, I'm trying to find a tool to reduce common objects to have nested arrays of objects.
ie.

```
SELECT *
FROM User
LEFT JOIN UserAddress ON UserAddress.user_id = User.user_id
LEFT JOIN Address ON Address.address_id = UserAddress.address_id;
```

we get a response of

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "test name",
    "address_id": 1,
    "address": "1234 address way"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "test name",
    "address_id": 2,
    "address": "5678 new address"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "name": "diff name",
    "address_id": 1,
    "address": "1234 address way"
  }
]
```

and I would like to use a tool in javascript that will reduce the array of objects to look like this

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "test name",
    "address": [
      {
        "address_id": 1,
        "address": "1234 address way"
      },
      {
        "address_id": 2,
        "address": "5678 new address"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "name": "diff name",
    "address_id": 1,
    "address": "1234 address way"
  }
]
```

but I'm not sure what that is called or if any tool exists that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that is a little generic, allowing you to specify what you're trying to collate and into what.  It uses a `Map` object in order to help with the collation of the target key (`user_id` in your case):

```
function collate(sourceArray, keyName, collectionName, collectionFields) {
    let collection = new Map();
    for (let item of sourceArray) {
        let targetObj = collection.get(item[keyName]);
        if (!targetObj) {
            targetObj = Object.assign({}, item);
            // remove the properties we are collecting
            for (let field of collectionFields) {
                delete targetObj[field];
            }
            targetObj[collectionName] = [];
            collection.set(item[keyName], targetObj);
        }
        let collectedObj = {};
        // copy over the fields we are collecting
        for (let field of collectionFields) {
            collectedObj[field] = item[field];
        }
        targetObj[collectionName].push(collectedObj);
    }
    // now convert Map to the final array
    return Array.from(collection.values());
}
```

Because I think it makes a lot more sense for whoever is using the resulting data, it always puts the address fields into an array, even if there is only one address and thus its an array of length `1`.  This will make it a lot easier for whoever is iterating this data to use it without all sorts of special conditions for reading it as the data is consistently located whether there is one or more than one address.  The reader can always get the length of the array to see for themselves  how many addresses there are.

And, you could use it on your data like this:

```js
let data = [
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "test name",
    "address_id": 1,
    "address": "1234 address way"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "test name",
    "address_id": 2,
    "address": "5678 new address"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "name": "diff name",
    "address_id": 1,
    "address": "1234 address way"
  }
];

function collate(sourceArray, keyName, collectionName, collectionFields) {
    let collection = new Map();
    for (let item of sourceArray) {
        let targetObj = collection.get(item[keyName]);
        if (!targetObj) {
            targetObj = Object.assign({}, item);
            // remove the properties we are collecting
            for (let field of collectionFields) {
                delete targetObj[field];
            }
            targetObj[collectionName] = [];
            collection.set(item[keyName], targetObj);
        }
        let collectedObj = {};
        // copy over the fields we are collecting
        for (let field of collectionFields) {
            collectedObj[field] = item[field];
        }
        targetObj[collectionName].push(collectedObj);
    }
    // now convert Map to the final array
    return Array.from(collection.values());
}

let result = collate(data, "user_id", "address", ["address", "address_id"]);
console.log(result);
```

Or, if you really don't want the one element array, you can post process that out at the end:

```js
let data = [
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "test name",
    "address_id": 1,
    "address": "1234 address way"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "test name",
    "address_id": 2,
    "address": "5678 new address"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "name": "diff name",
    "address_id": 1,
    "address": "1234 address way"
  }
];

function collate(sourceArray, keyName, collectionName, collectionFields) {
    let collection = new Map();
    for (let item of sourceArray) {
        let targetObj = collection.get(item[keyName]);
        if (!targetObj) {
            targetObj = Object.assign({}, item);
            // remove the properties we are collecting
            for (let field of collectionFields) {
                delete targetObj[field];
            }
            targetObj[collectionName] = [];
            collection.set(item[keyName], targetObj);
        }
        let collectedObj = {};
        // copy over the fields we are collecting
        for (let field of collectionFields) {
            collectedObj[field] = item[field];
        }
        targetObj[collectionName].push(collectedObj);
    }
    // now convert Map to the final array
    let result = Array.from(collection.values());

    // remove single element arrays and copy back to main object
    for (let item of result) {
        let array = item[collectionName];
        if (array.length === 1) {
            // remove the array
            delete item[collectionName];
            // copy the fields from the one array element back to the main object
            Object.assign(item, array[0]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

let result = collate(data, "user_id", "address", ["address", "address_id"]);
console.log(result);
```